# How to select sub document from a returned document of URL by jsoup?

Tags: java, jsoup, html-parsing

I use jsoup to parse HTML webpage. I get the document by this code:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
```

Now i want to select a sub-document of doc with special condition.
Help Please,

Comment: What about reading the documentation and API docs?

Comment: And by the way, without seeing the document structure and knowing which *elements* (that's what it's called in HTML) you want to select, how can we answer your question?

Comment: from start of a Title in a content of webpage to start another title.